# Error: App 'consistency' has migrations. Only the sqlmigrate and sqlflush commands can be used when an app has migrations

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-mssql

I have created an app titled "consistency" in Django. When I run

```
python manage.py sql consistency
```

I get this error:

```
App 'consistency' has migrations. Only the sqlmigrate and sqlflush commands can be used when an app has migrations.
```

What can I do to fix/avoid this error? Thanks in advance. I am using Python 3.4.

Comment: Advise on what? The error message tells you not to use the sql command. Why do you want to? Why don't you just run the migrations?

Comment: @DanielRoseman, how about advising on what a 'migration' is, how an app can 'have' them, and what sqlmigrate and sqlflush do, and why you might not want to run them.  (I got this error from the PyCharm/Django tutorial and wonder if it's because I forwent 'migrating' PyCharm settings from an earlier version, or does it mean something else entirely.)